# Program crashing when connecting to local database in 'Program Files' folder

Tags: c#, wpf, database, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'am getting an exception whenever I start the program from Program Files.
this is it : http://textuploader.com/lpl0
I tried running the app as admin but that didn't work I still get the same error but when I change the folder everything works fine.
The database is a local database created using VS 
I used a ADO.net entity data model too.
Thanks,

Comment: Looks like the database file(s) attributes are set to read-only :
The log cannot be rebuilt when the primary file is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

The "Program Files" folder is not really meant for storing data. To write to that location the context that is running the database engine needs to have "Administrator" rights. Consider using another location. It also seems that the provided password is wrong, but that seems quite obvious to me (considering the text in your file).